# Bus fahren - usage and grammar

Tags: usage, article

- Does

> *Ich fahre Bus.*

mean both

> *I drive a bus.* (=I'm a bus driver.)

and

> *I ride the bus.* (= I travel on a bus as a passenger.)
>   ?

- Why do you use *Bus* with no article here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Ich fahre Bus` can mean both: I am a bus driver or I ride in a bus. It depends on the context.

If you say `Ich fahre den Bus` or `Ich fahre einen Bus` you are the driver.

The sentence `Ich fahre mit einem Bus` means normally you ride on a bus. But depending on the context, it could also mean you are the driver. If it is clear you drive, then the sentence `Ich fahre mit einem Bus` expresses the detail, which vehicle you take.

Comment: So "Ich fahre Bus" can be both direct and indirect, and this is where the ambivalence comes from.

Comment: @Turion "Ich fahre Bus" means mostly not to drive a bus. Only in a talk between drivers.

Answer (score 2):

In this case "Bus" is treated like a mass noun just like water.

> Ich trinke Wasser.
>
> Ich fahre Bus.

The fact that English needs an article in your examples has more to do with the verbs that can't handle mass nouns, I guess. It does seem to work with car brands though... at least in colloquial use

> I drive Mercedes

Anyway. Here's an example that shows that treating bus as a mass noun is not unknown in English.

> I go by bus.

Comment: "Ich fahre Bus" means both "I'm a bus driver" and "I'm a passenger on a bus". Right?

Comment: @stillenat. Was that the question? Sorry, I missed that. Yes, it can mean both.

Comment: @Emanuel: There are much more situation where it means that you are a passenger.

Answer (score 0):

As stated previously, *Ich fahre Bus* can mean either or.  For future reference, when you're traveling somewhere *by way of* something, you would use **mit**.  For example:

> Ich komme mit dem Bus.
>
> Du kommst mit dem Rad.
>
> Sie bringt mich mit dem Auto zur Schule.
>
> Ich komme mit dem Moped nach Hause.

An exception to this would be using your feet:

> Meine Mutter geht zu Fuss nach Hause.